# sorting a table with an aggregiate function in ssrs 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a SSRS 2008 matrix with a column Point = max(point). I would like to make the table sort by Point column, and writing max(point) as an expression in tablix properties -> Sorting. But SSRS doesnt let me and warning me like: it is not allowed to use aggregiate functions while sorting. What can I do to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort aggregates on your Row or Column **Group** but not a table.

[image]